# How Do I set the image and button to appear at the bottom in android using XML

Tags: android

I want the image and button to appear right at the bottom, right now it is just floating half way across the screen and I dont like that how do I change it so It appears at the bottom of the screen? And what is the appropriate size for a button?

```
     <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HelpActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Connect 4 is a two-player game in which the players take turns dropping colour discs from the top into a seven-column, six-row vertically suspended grid. The aim is to get four in a row horizontally, vertically or diagonally and the first player to reach four in a row wins the game. "
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="22dip" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtBox"
    android:src="@drawable/connect4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/txtBox"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Back" />
```

Comment: Post your full xml so we can see what you have

Comment: FYI: you are allowed to accept answers by clicking the checkmark next to the appropriate one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the image and button to appear right at the bottom

Use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` to put them at the bottom of the `layout`. For your `ImageView` you have `android:layout_below="@+id/txtBox"` so that will put it below the `TextView`. If you want it to the right side of the screen then use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"`. If you are wanting the `Button` to the left of the `ImageView` then use `android:layout_alignToLeftOf="@id/imageView1"`.

So it would be something like

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".HelpActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtBox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView1"
    android:text="Connect 4 is a two-player game in which the players take turns dropping colour discs from the top into a seven-column, six-row vertically suspended grid. The aim is to get four in a row horizontally, vertically or diagonally and the first player to reach four in a row wins the game. "
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="22dip" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/connect4" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBack"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:text="Back" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

> And what is the appropriate size for a button?

This depends completely on you, your app, and what your users would expect/like. Know that hard-coding width and height sizes can be harder to make them look similar on different screens.